# How to mock a Sequence with a GUID Parameter using moq C#

Tags: c#, moq, mstest

I have the following concrete code:

```
 var allBookedPos = await _dataService.GetAllBookingsForVendorInAwitingApproval(purchaseOrder.VendorCode);

 foreach (var booking in allBookedPos)
 {
     // get the purchase order
     var po = await _purchaseOrderDataService.GetPurchaseOrderOnlyByIdAsync(booking.PurchaseOrderId);
 }
```

I've set my first mock to populate `allBookedPos` with:

```
BookingDataAccessMock.Setup(x => x.GetAllBookingsForVendorInAwitingApproval("A1248").Result).Returns(viewBookings);
```

This holds 2 records.

I'm now trying to mock the `GetPurchaseOrderOnlyByIdAsync` method, where the value passed in is a GUID.

Because I essentially want this method called twice I thought I'd be able to use `setupSequence` in the form:

```
PurchaseOrderDataMock.SetupSequence(X => X.GetPurchaseOrderByIdAsync(It.IsAny<Guid>)).Returns().Returns()
```

Where I populate each return with the values that I expect returned for each item. However, I get an error on `It.IsAny<Guid>` :

> Argument 1 cannot convert from method group to system.Guid

Comment: `It.IsAny<Guid>()` you're missing parenthesis there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`It.IsAny` is a method. You must invoke the method to get a new matcher instance:

```
It.IsAny<Guid>()
```

Comment: Cant believe I missed that. Thanks..